# Наполнение приложения данными

Tags: android

Пишу программу для изучения языка (осваиваю *андроид* таким образом). Всё необходимое написал, осталось наполнить массивы словами - английскими и их переводом. Вручную это долго, может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой и есть ссылки, или что-то подобное. Или подскажите, как поступить для ускорение процесса.

Необходимо что бы слова были разбиты по категориям.

Comment: По каким категорям слова должны быть разбиты? почему не использовать например MS api?

Comment: Категории типа : животные, продукты питания, природа, образование и т.д.

Comment: MS api не использую т.к. не знаю что это. Буду благодарен за пояснение

Comment: @АндройдАндройд MS api - это Microsoft API? А каким боком оно к андроиду имеет отношение?

Comment: ms translate api - это сервис майкрософта онлайн перевода. Но в вашем случае видимо придется руками создавать, например, xml-ky с тремя атрибутами, типа ru_name, translate, category.

Comment: ну как бы никто не запрещал им пользоваться=) в свое время прикручивал его, ничего сложного не было

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше и проще сделайте предзаполненную базу даных со словами и переводами. С базой даных проще даже ввести мультиязычность. Например получать слово по айди языка и айди слова. Так можно иметь доступ по сложному ключу к любому нужному слову на нужном языке.